# Is topology of pointwise convergence metrizable on the set of functions $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be the set of all monotone functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$. We know from Helly's selection theorem that $X$ is compact in the topology of pointwise convergence. Now I have the following two questions:

1. Is this topology metrizable? If yes with which metric?
2. Is monotonicity needed for $X$ to be compact? Could one apply Tychonoffs theorem to show that **all** functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ are compact?

Comment: Answer for 2). Yes, Tychonoff's Theorem gives compactness of $[0,1]^[0,1]$ and monotone functions form a  closed subset. But Helly's Theorem is about sequential compactness.

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Is this topology metrizable? If yes with which metric?

The space you refer to is also know as [the Helly space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly_space) and according to [L. Drewnowski, A. Michalak *"Generalized Helly spaces, continuity of monotone functions, and metrizing maps"*, Fundamenta Mathematicae 200 (2008)](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-doi-10_4064-fm200-2-4) the space is "separable, **nonmetrizable**, first-countable compact Hausdorff". The paper claims that the proof can be found in J. L. Kelley *"General Topology*" (which I haven't checked).

> 2. Is monotonicity needed for $X$ to be compact? Could one apply Tychonoffs theorem to show that **all** functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ are compact?

Yes, Tychonoff's theorem does imply that the space is compact. But, as mentioned by @KaviRamaMurthy in comments, Helly's theorem talks about *sequential* compactness. Note that in general, nonmetrizable case neither implies the other.

So is the space of all functions sequentially compact? It seems it is not, since it is listed in the famous ["Counterexamples in Topology"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology) book as a compact but not sequentially compact space.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, this was very helpful.

Comment: Is it 2nd-countable or not? A compact metrizable space must be 2nd-countable.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet it is not metrizable and so it is not second countable (for compact spaces these are equivalent).

Comment: Of course. What I meant to ask is whether there is a simple direct proof that it is not 2nd-countable, from which, if we  know that it is compact or separable, we would know it's not metrizable.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I don't know. I've actually spent quite some time trying to prove that it is not second countable. But couldn't do it. This doesn't seem trivial.